# Verifying that the position operator is not bounded.

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

[image]

Hello. What does it mean if the support is close to plus or minus infinite?

According to me, it means something like this
$ \text{supp}(\varphi)=[R,R+1]$ for $R$ enough large. Then $\| T\varphi\|_{2}=\int_{\text{supp}(\varphi)} |x\varphi(x)|^2dx= \int_{[R,R+1]}|x\varphi(x)|^2dx\geq R\int_{\text{supp}(\varphi)}|\varphi|^2dx=R\|\varphi\|_{2}$

If $R\to \infty$ then $\|T\varphi\|_{2}\to \infty$

How should it be in the right way?

Comment: Take $\phi =\chi_{(R,R+1)}$.

Comment: thanks. That is works!